# How to prevent switching tabs of tab control on Key Press and Mouse click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a wizard using Tab Control. Each page of the wizard gets navigated using the Wizard buttons. The problem comes when someone presses `Ctrl+Tab`, `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`, `Ctrl+Alt+Tab`, `Ctrl+End+ArrowKeys`, `Ctrl+End+MouseClick` which switches tab.There could be more scenarios that might occur in the future. As a temporary workaround I've suppressed such key combinations in PreviewKeyDown event. But is there a way I can completely disable switching tabs on Mouse or Key press; it should be only switched when its SelectedIndex is changed.

Please help.

Comment: So, you want to give the user a familiar control and then disable familiar means for them to interact with it? That sounds... counter-intuitive. Perhaps you've selected the wrong control to start from?

Comment: Yep. TabControl is probably not for you (or this use case at least).

Comment: I made exactly same mistake when started learning wpf year ago. You choose `TabControl` because it has several panels and headers, which you can easily switch in design time. Instead of `TabControl` you can create separate `UserControl` to hold content for each panel and display content of selected *tab* in `ContentControl`. You have to look into MVVM, because data templating of selected ViewModel is really neat way of dealing with wizard-alike content.

Comment: If you don't want the behavior of `TabControl`, then don't use `TabControl`. As other commenters have pointed out, there are alternative ways to build your UI, just as easily, and without confusing the user by presenting a familiar look that behaves incorrectly. The question is far too vague and broad for anyone to provide a good, specific answer addressing your exact need.